# Getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET from IIS with no information in logs

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, iis-10

I am getting a `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in Chrome when my ASP.NET server is trying to reply with an error.

Usually I can find information about server errors by looking in the log files, but there is nothing there.

Running a debugger over the reponse seems to show everything is OK, except at the end, Chrome tells me the connection was reset.

Here is the code that is handling the exception handling:

```
    try
    {
       ...
    }
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        Response.StatusDescription = e.Message;
        return new ContentResult {Content = "" };
    }
```

Chrome shows me `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in the console.

Using Fiddler, I get the error message `[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.`

If I [Enable Failed Request Tracing](https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85) in IIS, and open the generated xml file

```
    GENERAL_FLUSH_RESPONSE_END 


    BytesSent
    0 

    ErrorCode
    The parameter is incorrect.
     (0x80070057)
```

I have spent hours trying to debug this without much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by this line:

```
 Response.StatusDescription = e.Message;
```

When e.Message has a newline (`\r\n`) sequence inside.

The two options I had available to fix this error were:

**1.** Replace the line with:

```
 Response.StatusDescription = e.Message.Replace("\r\n"," ");
```

**2.** Replace the catch block with

```
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        return new ContentResult {Content = e.Message };
    }
```

Comment: Ran into this same problem. Thank you so much. I beat my head against the wall for about 2 days on this issue.

Answer (score 18):

I had this issue after playing around with some virtual domains on the localhost and assigning SSL Certificates. Selecting the IIS Development Certificate for the current domain the error disappeared.

Comment: For some reason, I also got this same error and couldn't figure out what was the issue. After manually deleting the https binding and creating it again, everything started working again...

Comment: thanks a lot for saving us time ! it was indeed the binding certificate that got unset while creating a new site.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. Thankyou.